# get column values from SSRS report

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with Row group and Column Group, which makes a type of pivot table for my data.
I want to make a calculation for each column values, which I can't do inside the SSRS Report (CPK)
I can do the calculation in vb.net dll, but I need to send to the dll an array of all column data,
How can I do that?

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: show and tell what you want to achieve.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.